# How does rancher schedule services to specific hosts?

Tags: docker, rancher

How does rancher decide which host to schedule a certain service to? Does it consider available memory and CPU? Rancher is frequently overloading my hosts and is causing them to crash.  As far can I can tell, services are being scheduled to hosts with the least number of services running on them. Is there a way to change this? I'm using cattle as my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default is by number of containers on the host, as we have no useful information on how much resource each container should be expected to take.  You can define the resource usage of each service and resource limits of each host and then they will be taken into account:  http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/rancher-services/scheduler/#resource-constraints